# Why is my WCF FaultException unhandled?

Tags: c#, wcf, exception, async-await, faultexception

I have a service based on the following contract (abridged):

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ISchedulerService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void Process(bool isForced);
}
```

The germane (IMHO) part of the implementation is:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, UseSynchronizationContext = false)]
public class SchedulerService : ISchedulerService
{
    public async void Process(bool isForced)
    {
        try
        {
            var prevStatus = Status;
            Status = SchedulerStatus.Processing;
            await ProcessListings();
            Status = prevStatus;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new FaultException(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private static Task ProcessListings()
    {
        throw new Exception("ProcessListings failed.");           
        return Task.Delay(5000);
    }
}
```

The service is currently hosted in a tiny console app:

```
class Program
{
    private static readonly SchedulerService Scheduler = SchedulerService.Instance;
    private static ServiceHost schedulerHost;

    protected static void OnStart()
    {
        try
        {
            if (schedulerHost != null)
            {
                schedulerHost.Close();
                schedulerHost = null;
            }
            schedulerHost = new ServiceHost(Scheduler);
            schedulerHost.Open();
            Scheduler.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //EventLog.WriteEntry("Exception: " + ex.Message);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

And, finally, the client:

```
private readonly SchedulerServiceClient _proxy= new SchedulerServiceClient();
...
void ExecuteProcessNowCommand()
{
    try
    {
        _proxy.Process(true);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (exception is SchedulerException)
        {
            MessageBoxFacility.ProcessingError((SchedulerException)exception);
        }
    }
}
```

where `SchedulerServiceClient` is the proxy that is generated when I add a service reference. Up until now, I have successfully hosted the WCF inside a live Windows Service and tested non-exception functionality. Everything was fine until I added exception handling. I know this is a complex scenario, but most examples I have seen suggest that the `FaultException` would at least be caught by the general `Exception` handler in the client. My debugger makes me guess the exception doesn't even make it to the proxy, and it remains unhandled in the MVC code. When I hit 'continue' enough, I end up at a screen telling me the stack contains only external code. This is the stack trace for that external code:

```
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.&amp;lt;ThrowAsync&amp;gt;b__1(Object state)
at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()</ExceptionString></Exception></TraceRecord>
```

This makes me think my use of `async` in the MCV service might me playing a role, but then maybe it's only an innocent middleman. Please help me try and determine why the exception is not even propagated to the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exceptions in `async` methods are stored in the returned task. `async void` methods don't return a task and so the exception is thrown on a `ThreadPool` thread tearing down the `AppDomain`.

**Don't use `async void` anywhere** other than event handlers.

If you return a task you can `await` that task and the exception will be rethrown.

Comment: The exception is properly caught by the method that waits on the async method, i.e. `Process` does catch the exception thrown by `ProcessListings`. The `AppDomain` still seems fine while `Process` throws the exception it catches.

Comment: @ProfK `ProcessListings` isn't an `async` method. It just returns a task. `Process` is the `async` method throwing the exception, which is not caught.

Comment: Aha, thanks! I have just removed all asynchrony, and the exception gets to the client. So, should I now rather create the task in `Process`, and `await` the generated async method in the proxy?

Comment: @ProfK pretty much. Don't create a task, just change the return value and the compiler will generate that for you. You can look at this for more info: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/613678/Task-based-Asynchronous-Operation-in-WCF

Comment: Thank you. I have begun another long climb of learning. I'm still near the bottom of the one where you mix WPF, timers, WCF, and a Windows Service.